# lm-sensors stops reading temp1, causes overheating

Tags: suspend, thinkpad, overheating, fan, temperature

Once in a while, after waking my laptop from sleep (a Lenovo Thinkpad T440 on Ubuntu 18.04) [lm-sensors](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto) will fail to read temp1 and as a result, [thinkfan](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/thinkfan.1.html) seems to think the temperature is low and does not start the fan. There are other temperature readings still available in sensors and I see the temperature of some getting as high as 80C. Restarting the PC often does not solve the problem, but shutting it down and turning it back on will most often do it. Anyone ever had this kind of problem? This is what the output of sensors then look like this

```
    coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:           0 RPM
temp1:         N/A
temp2:         +0.0°C
temp3:         +0.0°C
temp4:         +0.0°C
temp5:         +0.0°C
temp6:         +0.0°C
temp7:         +0.0°C
temp8:         +0.0°C
```

Edit:

```
$ ps auxc | grep -i therm
root       154  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   May26   0:00 acpi_thermal_pm
root       956  0.0  0.0 186996   420 ?        Ssl  May26   0:01 thermald
```

Comment: Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to determine your BIOS version. Then go to the Lenovo web site and check for a newer version. Report back.

Comment: on lenovo support site, it says the bios update supports only windows. is there a way to make the update work with ubuntu?

Comment: Some BIOS let you update directly from the current BIOS. Check your docs. Some manufacturer web sites provide multiple ways to update... like a bootable .iso. If a Windows .exe file is all they supply, you can try creating a bootable freeDOS USB flash drive and doing it that way. Give me the URL for the support page you were looking at. What is your current BIOS?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I should be able to build the bootable usb with a windows machine. current bios is GJET71WW (2.21 ) and the url is https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ca/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t440/downloads/DS035965

Comment: Or you can download the .iso file and build a bootable CD/DVD. Also, show me `ps auxc | grep -i therm`.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: I did the bios update and the problem has not appeared again since (but it was a bit random so its hard to tell)

Comment: its been a few days since last time i had the problem so im going to declare this problem solved! the bios update was all that was needed after all. thank you heynnema

Comment: Great news! Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**thermald**

<strike>`ps auxc | grep -i therm` shows me that you've got at least two thermal control processes running.</strike>

$ ps auxc | grep -i therm

```
root       154  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   May26   0:00 acpi_thermal_pm
root       956  0.0  0.0 186996   420 ?        Ssl  May26   0:01 thermald
```

Purge <strike>`thermald`</strike>... and `thinkfan`...

<strike>sudo apt-get purge thermald</strike>

```
sudo apt-get purge thinkfan
```

**lm-sensors**

After installing `lm-sensors`, be sure to configure it by running `sensors-detect`.

**BIOS**

Lenovo Thinkpad T440

You have BIOS GJET71WW (2.21).

The current BIOS is GJETA4WW (2.54) and can be downloaded [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ca/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t440/downloads/DS035965).

If you don't have Windows, you can either build a bootable freeDOS USB flash, or download the .iso and build a bootable CD/DVD.

The updated BIOS may help with your fan/temp problem.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: acpi_thermal_pm is the ACPI Thermal Zone driver.  thermald uses the ACPI driver for controlling fans.  From my experience, sensors-detect rarely gets you anywhere on a laptop in regards to controlling the fans.

Comment: Why?  The first part of the answer is wrong as previously stated.  The second part uninstalled both fan control utils that typically work on laptops with no recommendation for a replacement.  The third section is in the post and is already installed.  BIOS update might solve it.