# Do both thermald and acpi_thermal_pm do thermal management? Is one recommended over the other?

Tags: overheating, acpi

I heard that `thermald` is useful to prevent overheating, so I installed it on my system (running 20.04 LTS). When I run `ps auxc | grep -i therm`, I see the following:

```bsh
root         166  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   21:17   0:00 acpi_thermal_pm
root       22017  0.0  0.0 136068  5428 ?        Ssl  21:51   0:00 thermald
```

Leading me to realize I already had `acpi_thermal_pm` (the ACPI thermal driver) running, which was perhaps already doing thermal management. After searching for more information, I found conflicting information about running these two processes at the same time. Some said to purge `thermald`, and some said thermald uses the ACPI driver. For example:

- The answer to this question [lm-sensors stops reading temp1, causes overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243952/lm-sensors-stops-reading-temp1-causes-overheating) and the comments on that answer seem to disagree about what to do with the two processes.
- This wiki page [Thermal issues](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues) also seems to indicate that `thermald` is recommended for better configuration.

So, is `thermald` the way to go, and should the `acpi_thermal_pm` process still be running along with it? Or should I purge `thermald`?

Comment: As the author, I edited the [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243952/lm-sensors-stops-reading-temp1-causes-overheating). You can leave both running.